# Restarting Publisher

Tags: ros, publisher, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I just want to share with you some issue I have detected and might be a bug, but probably it's just that I'm missing something. BTW, I'm using diamondback.

I have a couple of nodes: (A) publisher and (B) subscriber. Actually, I'm using image_transport publishers/subscribers. This is how to reproduce the issue given to nodes like above (of course, B subscribes to a topic that A publishes):

run A + run B + stop (Ctrl+C) A + run A

After that, B doesn't receive any msgs from A.

However, if you do:

run B + run A + stop (Ctrl+C) A + run A

it works ---and, of course, you can repeat the last two steps any number of times.

I just wonder why the first "sequence" doesn't work. Is it because it must be done the second way? ---i.e. run subscribers before publishers.

Thanks,

Enrique

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11474/restarting-publisher/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2011-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-10-08**:
I think you've just find the problem, because I'm roslaunching each node (instead of rosrunning). Now I see why I should always do roscore separately; I used to rely on the roscore automatically launched with the first launch file. Thank you!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-08**:
Is `roscore` running continuously throughout these tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a side-effect of the fact that `roslaunch` only starts `roscore` if it was not already running.

In either case, starting `roscore` first should eliminate the problem:

- roscore + run A + run B + stop (Ctrl+C) A + run A
- roscore + run B + run A + stop (Ctrl+C) A + run A

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1